# Help with steam install Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, steam

When i try to install steam it says

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:libGL.so.1
```

then i tryied a lot of commands and its not working also for some reason i don't got Software Boutique in the Ubuntu Center

And thats what it says if i type in sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-welcome

(german)
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig

```
E: Paket ubuntu-mate-welcome kann nicht gefunden werden.
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add support to 32 bit libraries.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try to reinstall steam.

Comment: i did it and it says the same again..

Comment: omg it worked later thx very much and god bless you