# Ubuntu 16.04: Steam not able to install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 and libgl1-mesa-glx:i386

Tags: package-management, dependencies, steam

**After an update Steam does not start properly anymore and says:**

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
    libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

**When Installing it tells:**

```
.........
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ibus : Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 (>= 3.8.5) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: adwaita-icon-theme but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: ibus-gtk3 but it is not going to be installed or
                    ibus-qt4 but it is not going to be installed or
                    libqt5gui5 but it is not going to be installed
 libcheese-gtk25 : Depends: libcogl20 (>= 1.17.4) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 but it is not going to be installed
 libcheese8 : Depends: libclutter-gst-3.0-0 (>= 3.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libclutter-1.0-0 : Depends: libcogl-pango20 (>= 1.17.4) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libcogl-path20 (>= 1.17.4) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libcogl20 (>= 1.21.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 : Depends: libcogl20 (>= 1.17.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libegl1-mesa : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri (= 1:17.1.4-0~x~padoka0) but it is not going to be installed
 libgbm1 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri (= 1:17.1.4-0~x~padoka0) but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-glx : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 1:17.1.4-0~x~padoka0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri (>= 7.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Breaks: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (!= 1:17.1.4-0~x~padoka0) but 17.3~git1708090730.a1c9a6~gd~x is to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-glx (!= 17.3~git1708090730.a1c9a6~gd~x) but 1:17.1.4-0~x~padoka0 is to be installed
 libgtk-3-0 : Depends: libgtk-3-common (>= 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libwayland-egl1-mesa (>= 10.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                       libwayland-egl1
              Recommends: libgtk-3-bin
 libqgsttools-p1 : Depends: libqt5multimediawidgets5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                            libqt5multimediawidgets5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5gui5-gles : Depends: libgles2-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                            libgles2
 libqt5quick5-gles : Depends: libgles2-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                              libgles2
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 : Depends: libwayland-egl1-mesa (>= 10.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libwayland-egl1
                        Recommends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 but it is not going to be installed
 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin : Depends: qml-module-ubuntu-components
                                           Depends: qml-module-ubuntu-performancemetrics
                                           Depends: qml-module-ubuntu-test but it is not going to be installed
 system-config-printer-gnome : Depends: adwaita-icon-theme but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 but it is not going to be installed
 unity-asset-pool : Depends: adwaita-icon-theme but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
Press return to continue:
```

**So I am not able to install these packages. I also tried:**

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-xenial:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc6:i386 is already the newest version (2.23-0ubuntu9).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-xenial:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Still this is not successful. I read other topics on this but no solution yet. Can anybody help me? I don't understand the problem here.**

Comment: I have the same issue, and it looks like we need to add 32-bit libs. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941966/help-with-steam-install-ubuntu-14-04) may be the solution, although it hasn't worked for me. The OP said it worked later, maybe after a restart?